# Print the text entered on keyboard onto GLUT window?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Trying to display the characters typed on keyboard, I am using the following code:

```
 void myKey(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  if (key == 13) // enter key
{
    return;
}
   glRasterPos2f(xpos, 600);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // text color
   glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, key); // print the color

   glFlush();
   xpos += 15;
   player1[i] = key;
   i += 1;
}
```

It prints the text entered onto the screen but, it doesn't exit as it is supposed to when I press enter.  I want the the code to display the player name of the player1 and store it in an array then exit when I press enter and then continue to accept the second player name.

Answer (score 1):

Only do OpenGL stuff in the display callback.

You need to break your text entry into two pieces:

1. Keyboard/array handling in the `glutKeyboardFunc()` callback.  Once you're done modifying the name list post a redisplay event.
2. String rendering in the `glutDisplayFunc()` callback, where you iterate over the name vector and display each string.

Like so:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector< string > names( 1 );
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 13 )
    {
        // enter key
        names.push_back( "" );
    }
    else if( key == 8 )
    {
        // backspace
        names.back().pop_back();
    }
    else
    {
        // regular text
        names.back().push_back( key );
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glOrtho( 0, w, 0, h, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    for( size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i )
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << ( i + 1 ) << ": " << names[i];

        void* font = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;
        const int fontHeight = glutBitmapHeight( font );
        glRasterPos2i( 10, h - ( fontHeight * ( i + 1 ) ) );
        glutBitmapString( font, (const unsigned char*)( oss.str().c_str() ) );
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```